# IIF statement in ms access query returns #error when testing for null

Tags: sql, ms-access

The `IIF function` in my query is returning #ERROR when I know the record i'm querying meets the criteria. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl1.ItemCode, IIf(IsNull([tbl2].[True Available Quantity]) Or 
[tbl2].[True Available Quantity]="",[tbl1].[EvalInstock],[tbl2].[True 
Available Quantity]) AS InStock
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.ItemCode = tbl2.[Item No#]
WHERE (((tbl1.ItemCode)="3003"));
```

The WHERE part is just to limit this query for testing on a record I know has data in the [tbl2].[True Available Quantity] field.

The ultimate goal is to return all items in tbl1 and use the `[True Available Quantity]` value from tbl2 if it is there and if not, use `EvalInstock` from tbl1. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Can you show the definitions and some sample data for `tbl1` and `tbl2`?

Comment: Is Tbl2.[True Available Quantity] a string?

Comment: no tbl2.[true available quantity] is a number. That is probably it. I can't change or really see the data type of EvalInstock but i believe it is a string. Can i cast tbl2.[true available quantity] to a string in my query? Thanks already, I completely overlooked considering the datatype of the fields!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter if [true available quantity] is number and EvalInstock is string because if EvalInstock is a string the return from either field will automatically cast as a string. I did a test to confirm. So something else is wrong.

If [true available quantity] is a number type field can't compare to empty string so remove that condition.

Is ItemCode a text type field? If not, remove the quote marks.

If you use IsNull() might as well use Nz(): `Nz([True Available Quantity], [EvalInstock]) AS InStock`
Review http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html

Comment: removing the comparison to the empty string did it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You problem is most likely, that VBA always checks both conditions:

```
IsNull([tbl2].[True Available Quantity]) Or [tbl2].[True Available Quantity]=""
```

thus, if Null, the second condition also returns Null which can't be compared, and then *IIf* doesn't know what to do.

So try with *Nz*:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.ItemCode, 
    Nz([tbl2].[True Available Quantity], [tbl1].[EvalInstock]) AS InStock
FROM 
    tbl1 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl2 
    ON tbl1.ItemCode = tbl2.[Item No#]
WHERE 
    tbl1.ItemCode = "3003";
```